# Overflow several inline vertical lists horizontally

Tags: html, css, overflow, inline

I have an information bar at the bottom of my site. It has several inline-block elements that are displayed horizontally. As you can see in the fiddle, when the information in the inline-block elements gets too large vertically, it overflows below the bottom edge of the information bar. I would like this stuff to overflow to the right, similar to a newspaper column.

jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TLfHG/)

```
<div class="information-bar">
    <div class="information">
        <div class="title">Section Title</div>
        information <br />
        information2 <br />
        information3 <br />
        information4 <br />
        information5 <br />
    </div>
    <div class="information">
        <div class="title">Section Title</div>
        information <br />
        information2 <br />
        information3 <br />
        information4 <br />
        information5 <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to transform this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

I have tried the css3 columns method: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLfHG/1/).
Unfortunately it is only designed to work with one column, I believe, because this happens:

[image]

Comment: This is the sort of thing that could be done easily with JavaScript in the client side or with any server-side language generating the HTML on the server-side. I think that might be the simplest, most maintainable option but I'll jut have to see what the wizards here come up with :)

Comment: Why not use a `table`, they're ment to arrang data...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm using this with mustache on the client side! It's logic-less, so I'd have to write some javascript to arrange stuff. It would be easy indeed, but it would be a bit ugly. We have two great solutions already!

Comment: @LinkinTED Yes, I would use a table if there are no other options. Tables are messy, though, and I try to stay away from them.

Comment: @LevDubinets, I don't agree with you on that. All elements are designed to a specific function. You use a `ul` or `ol` to create a list, you use `p` for paragraphs, etc. Than why not use a `table` to arrange your data? I think it's messy when you don't use a table... you can see that in your situation you need to a whole bunch of tricks to get the result... with a table you don't need to do tricks, it does what you need.

Comment: @LinkinTED I agree with using elements to perform their given function. Tables are designed to display tabular data. But this is not tabular data, it is a column-based layout. With tables, I would not be able to just have a list of "info-elements", I would have to split them into separate table columns. It breaks up the content for the sake of presentation (this is a Bad Thing in the world of web-design). In other words, tables are for data that depends on both columns and rows. In my case, I don't care about the rows, only about the columns.

Comment: @LevDubinets, okay, then I misunderstood your question. I agree that tables shouldn't be used as the structure of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. There's one issue, however: when the windows is too small, the second information set is displayed below. But I think this isn't a big issue, since it's not that wide.

```
.information-bar {
width:100%;
height: 100px;
background: #999;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

.information-bar .information {
display: block;
height: 95px;
-webkit-column-width:144px;
-webkit-column-gap:16px;
-moz-column-width:144px;
-moz-column-gap:16px;
column-width:144px;
column-gap:16px;
-moz-column-count:2;
-webkit-column-count:2;
column-count:2;
}
div.information
{
float:left;
width: 304px; /*quick math: 144*2+16=304*/
}
```

Comment: ah! This is cool. I've found another solution that works in IE as well, but is dependent on knowing the column width.

Answer (score 1):

Using the insight from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rondevera/167627), we can organize the information in columns, but we must know the maximum column width beforehand:

```
.information-bar {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.information-bar .information {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 95px;
}
p.info-element {
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
p.info-element:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+5) {
    margin-left: 0em;
}
p.info-element:nth-child(6) {
    margin-top: -6em;
}
p.info-element:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+10) {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

The nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+5) selector allows us to select a range of elements (as discussed in the gist). An interesting css hack!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46XRe/)